# Set of bounded increasing functions is not totally bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that the set of bounded and increasing functions $\mathbb R \rightarrow [0,1]$ is not totally bounded in the supremum norm. First I am trying to show this for the simple case of any function $\mathbb R \rightarrow [0,1]$ rather than for increasing functions.

My approach is to find some $\delta$ such that there is no finite set that can cover $\mathcal F$ in sup norm but I can't see why such a universal $\delta$ would exist.

Comment: Any set? What about  a finite, or empty set?

Comment: Ah my mistake. I mean "show that in general a set of bounded and increasing functions..."

Comment: A  totally bounded set is  a bounded set because it is a subset of  the union of a finite set of open balls with finite radii. BTW do you know the Arzela-Ascoli theorem?

Comment: Did my explanation indicate that I'm misunderstanding the definition of totally bounded sets? I am familiar with Arzela-Ascoli, maybe we can use it to show the claim by showing that the set of functions in question is not necessarily equicontinuous? Isn't there a more straightforward way?

Comment: $X$ is totally bounded iff for every $r>0$ there is a finite cover of $X$ by open balls of radius $r$.

Comment: A finite set is not going to be not totally bounded. So the 'any' part of the question is questionable.

Comment: @daw i updated the question

Comment: @daw it's not obvious to me that it is not bounded in sup norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any increasing function $f:\mathbb R \to (0,\frac{1}{2})$ you like the most, for example $f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}(\arctan(x) + \frac{\pi}{2}) $

For every $n$ define $f_n:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$ as follows:

$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x \in (-\infty,n] \\ f(n) + \frac{1}{2}(x-n) & x \in (n,n+1] \\ \frac{1}{2} + f(x) & x \in (n+1,\infty)\end{cases} $$

You can check yourself that it is indeed a continuous function for any $n$ (it looks like arctan, but at interval $[n,n+1]$ it has linear growth of height $\frac{1}{2}$.

The point is, for any $n,m \in \mathbb N_+$ such that $n \neq m$, you have $$\|f_n-f_m\| \ge \frac{1}{2} $$
Indeed, if $n < m$ then $f_n(n+1) = \frac{1}{2} + f(n+1)$, while $f_m(n+1) = f(n+1)$

Hence, we've found a countable family of functions (bounded, increasing and continuous) such that every two are at distance (in $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$) at least $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence our set cannot be totally bounded.